# Convergence and limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have to find out whether $1/(n^2+n)$ and $n/(n^2+n)$ for n$\in$N are convergent and then find their limiting value.
I think that:

$$\lim_{n\to ∞} 1/(n^2+n)=\lim_{n\to ∞}1/n/(n^2/n+n/n) =0 $$

and

$$\lim_{n\to ∞}n/(n^2+n)=\lim_{n\to ∞}n/n/(n^2/n+n/n) =0.$$

And I think that both of them are monotonically decreasing for. So both of them are converging to the limit $0$? But how can I show it purely formally?

Comment: Being monotonically decreasing is not at all sufficient to justify the limit $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$0 <\frac n {n^{2}+n} <\frac  1 n$ and $0 <\frac 1 {n^{2}+n} <\frac  1 n$. Use Squeeze Theorem.